# Theming mime mail rule email send

Tags: mimemail

I've got a rule that fires properly and sends an email after a comment is saved. I want to theme this specific rule using the documented method.

My template name: `mimemail-message--rules--ticketcomments.html.twig`

I created a mail system module with the same "key" name.

Theming to the `mimemail-message--rules.html.twig` does work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which documented method?

Comment: @cilefen I think he's referring to [`mimemail-message--[module]--[key].html.twig`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/mime-mail/theming-email-sent-by-mime-mail)

Comment: Hey! Yep that's correct. In the contrib template files there's some instructions on how. In D7 I believe you can set a key for the email, in D9 that doesn't appear to be there.

Comment: [D9 version does have it](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/mimemail/-/blob/8.x-1.x/mimemail.module#L73). Maybe you have the wrong key? You could check it with [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/9.2.x) and log the key, `\Drupal::logger('my_module')->error($message['key']);` and check the Drupal log.

Comment: First thank you for the help! Added the hook to my custom module that was already trying to add a key - watchdog comes back with 'Column 'message' cannot be null'.